# Why is my game so much slower on Phaser 3 when I try and port it from Phaser 2?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, game-physics

I have a snake game I made in Phaser 2. I am trying to create a phaser 3 version. When my snake gets too long, it really lags. This was the original code from Phaser 2

```
  var part = snakePath.pop();

  part.setTo(snakeHead.x, snakeHead.y);

  snakePath.unshift(part);

  for (var i = 1; i <= numSnakeSections - 1; i++)
  {
    snakeSection[i].x = (snakePath[i * snakeSpacer]).x;
    snakeSection[i].y = (snakePath[i * snakeSpacer]).y;

    if(i==numSnakeSections-3){
      emitter.x = snakeSection[i].x;
      emitter.y = snakeSection[i].y;
    }
  }
```

`snakePath` is an array where each section of the snake will follow. Each `snakeSpace` is the amount of space between each body section.

Phaser 3's version is as follows:

```
  var part = snakePath.pop();

  part=new Phaser.Geom.Point(snakeHead.x, snakeHead.y);

  snakePath.unshift(part);

  for (var i = 1; i <= numSnakeSections - 1; i++)
  {
    snakeSection[i].x = (snakePath[i * snakeSpacer]).x;
    snakeSection[i].y = (snakePath[i * snakeSpacer]).y;
  }
```

The body segments between become far apart as the game cannot keep up with the rendering. Is there a solution?

P.S. I based my code off of a Phaser 2 example: https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/snake

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my sprite images were too large. It was 1000x1000. I set it to 25x25 and it worked fine